# click event seems sometime works and sometime doesn't work in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
@Then ("^I hover on (.+) menu and (.+) submenu$")
        public void mousehover(String elementName,String subMenu) throws InterruptedException{
            Actions actions = new Actions(webdriver);
            WebElement menuHoverLink = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = '" + elementName + "']"));
            actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = '" + subMenu + "']"))).click().build().perform();
            System.out.println("Sub menu "+subMenu+" Has been clicked");
        }
```

> Blockquote Hi every one. This is my code to done mouse hover event and then click sub link. But most of the time sub link click event is working. But some time which is not works. The mouse hover event has been done. But sub link click event is not triggering. Really don't know why this happen. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I would try somethin like moving to where you want to click and then just clicking. With hover menus you can get some odd behaviour from selenium about when an elemenet is and isnt clickable. Try;

```
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink).Perform();
//wait til clickable, you are sleeping, a wait til element is both displayed and enabled would be better - can explain more if needed
action.Click().Perform();
```

note: I think just using peform will build the action without explicitly stating

EDIT:
I would assume that sometimes it takes longer than the 2seconds sleep time for the the element to be clickable. What exception is thrown?

Instead of thread.sleep use a wait to decide if the element can be clicked, something like:

```
public void WaitForElementToBeClickable(IWebElement element)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
            {
                if (IsElementDisplayed(element) && IsElementEnabled(element))
                    return true;
                else return false;
            });
    }

    public Boolean IsElementEnabled(IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            return (element.Enabled);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsElementDisplayed(IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            return (element.Displayed);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you pls explain me in detail with an exampls. And FYI, I wanted to know why sometimes the ClickEvent is working properly and sometimes it is not. (For the same coding). Will be helpful if you provide with an example codes.

Comment: <ul>Business<li>
<a>Chain performance</a>
<a>Week days Report</a>
<a>Top X Report</a>
</li>
</ul>. Exact problem has been found.but don't know how to handle.Here, The first two anchors are working(clickable) but no the third one. Also first two tabs are highlighted when mousehover and last one remains disabled.  Which means when hover on first two tabs that are highlighted then it clickable.But in third move to element  has been skipped
Kindly help me on this. 
Function : "Move to Element" is  not workin on the third tab(but works on first two tabs). 
Getting an Exception as "No Such Element".